# Filter common values among categories (two or more) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

We have created various categories using WordPress CMS. We have to filter the data by clicking categories. I need to filter the category values (data) when I click more than two category. I have used `array_intersect` concepts for picking common values among categories. But It's working for two categories alone.

When I click (which is a select option) more than two categories, it didn't work. Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Can you provide more informations? Code would be great... Or the site where we can see what you mean.

Comment: I'm using this code(which is a inner join concept) $query=query_posts(array('category_and('33,45,56')); to filter the common values in the categories 33,45,56. But when I use this code, it retrieveall category values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work (but untested for now):

```
<?php

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'cat' => '33,45,56'
)

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) {

  while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
    /* do stuff here */
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();

}

?>
```

Check the [WP Query Codex (Category Parameters)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) for more information

Comment: this is retrive all the datas beloning to these three(33,45,56) categories.. it doesn't pick the common values.. this is the issue..

Comment: and what are your "common values"? A taxonomy? A postmeta? I don't understand whats behind these common values

Comment: The common value in the sense "A taxonomy".